# Как задать настройки отображения параметров функций в теме для VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Создаю свою тему VS Code и хочу, чтобы параметры функций в JS отображались отдельным цветом, как в теме Dracula например.
Скопировал как мне кажется соответствующие настройки из Dracula, но все равно не работает:

```
 
{
      "name": "Function parameters",
      "scope": [
        "entity.name.variable.parameter",
        "meta.at-rule.function variable",
        "meta.at-rule.mixin variable",
        "meta.function.arguments variable.other.php",
        "meta.selectionset.graphql meta.arguments.graphql variable.arguments.graphql",
        "variable.parameter"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": "italic",
        "foreground": "#FFB86C"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Generics, templates, and mapped type declarations",
      "scope": [
        "entity.name.type.type-parameter",
        "meta.indexer.mappedtype.declaration entity.name.type",
        "meta.type.parameters entity.name.type"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#FFB86C"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "JSDoc-style comment parameters",
      "scope": ["comment.block.documentation variable"],
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#FFB86C",
        "fontStyle": "italic"
      }
    }
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы можете посмотреть через `>Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` нужную информацию, наведя на нужный участок кода.